# How access div within gridview with Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all information from [archdaily](https://www.archdaily.com/search/projects/categories/residential-architecture?page=1) over multiple pages of the website (e.g. from page 1 to 20).

**The html structure looks like:**

```html
    <div>
      <div class = 'afd-container-main afd-container-main--margin-bottom nft-container-main-search clearfix afd-mobile-margin search-container'>
        ::before
          <div>
            <div class='gridview'>
              <div>
                <div data-insights-category>
                  <a href = '...'> # this is the htmls i wanted
```

**The code I'm using is**

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')
for foo in soup.find_all('div'):
    bar = foo.find('div', attrs={'class': 'afd-container-main afd-container-main--margin-bottom nft-container-main-search clearfix afd-mobile-margin search-container'})
    print(bar.text)
```

**Error message**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: First at all, take a look into your soup - In almost 99% of cases, the information people are looking for is not in the soup - Just to improve your question, it would be great to add also information how you get your html, fix typos and the correct error message - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Because the question does not reveal, how you get your html, it is not that easy to answer.

If you use `requests`, you wont get the results that way, cause the site deals with dynamic served content.

###### Alternativ approaches:

- Get information with `requests` via api (*provides even more information - categories, company,...*)

  ```
  #iterate over pages
  for p in range(1,3):
      r = requests.get(f'https://www.archdaily.com/search/api/v1/us/projects/categories/residential-architecture?page={p}') #url of next page
      for item in r.json()['results']:
          # iterate over results and print title+url
          print(item['title'], item['url'])
  ```
- Get renderd `html` via Selenium

#### Example

```
import requests

for p in range(1,2):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.archdaily.com/search/api/v1/us/projects/categories/residential-architecture?page={p}') #url of next page
    for item in r.json()['results']:
        print(item['title'], item['url'])
```

#### Output

```
Wooden House / derksen | windt architecten https://www.archdaily.com/972995/wooden-house-derksen-windt-architecten?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
PLA2 House / Dersyn Studio https://www.archdaily.com/972939/pla2-house-dersyn-studio?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
gjG House / BLAF Architecten https://www.archdaily.com/951845/gjg-house-blaf-architecten?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
Leopoldo 1201 Residential Building / aflalo/gasperini arquitetos https://www.archdaily.com/972959/leopoldo-1201-residential-building-aflalo-gasperini-arquitetos?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
Sayang House / Carlos Gris Studio https://www.archdaily.com/972773/sayang-house-carlos-gris-studio?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
Nong Ho 17 House / Skarn Chaiyawat https://www.archdaily.com/972911/nong-ho-17-house-skarn-chaiyawat?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
LÂM’s Home / AD+studio https://www.archdaily.com/972794/lams-home-ad-plus-studio?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
Limestone House / John Wardle Architects  https://www.archdaily.com/972958/limestone-house-john-wardle-architects?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
Quay Wall House / Thomas Kemme Architects https://www.archdaily.com/971781/quay-wall-house-thomas-kemme-architects?ad_source=search&ad_medium=projects_tab
...
```

Comment: i didn't know the dynamic content and stuck there. many thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: We are all here to learn and evolve - you will develop strategies to avoid such stumbling blocks in the future. Look for offical api, api calls, use selenium, ....